# function in background access to global variable

Tags: bash

I am running a bunch of tasks on a variable number of servers from a serverlist. I am wanting to provide a way of knowing the percentage complete of the running tasks.

I have implemented the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

items=4
complete=0

# Show progress dots
progress(){
# echo -n "Running tasks..."
  while [[ $complete -le $items ]]
  do
  pct=$(($complete * 100 / $items))
  echo  "\r$pct%\c\b" 
  sleep 1
  done
}

#get list function
function getlist() {
for i in $(cat fakelist.txt)
do
nexec -i $i hostname >>hosts.txt
((complete+=1))
done

}

#function calls

progress &


MYSELF=$!
getlist


# Kill progress
kill $MYSELF >/dev/null 2>&1

echo -n "...done."
echo
```

It appears that the progress function which I am putting in the background has no access to the global variable complete and therefore is unable to compute a percentage. Is there another way to achieve this without having to change everything?

Comment: Can't do: Backgrounded commands aren't just in a different thread, they're in a whole different process. Different process space -> no shared variables.

Comment: Also, don't use the `function` keyword -- it makes your code incompatible with POSIX shells but adds no value.

Comment: BTW, didn't we just tell you not to use `for i in $(cat ...)`? In case that was someone else -- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Comment: ...also, you're ignoring the answer you were given -- to replace the `sleep 1` with the `nexec` command -- which would have let you not need to background anything at all (by putting the status line update in the foreground).

Comment: Yeah, but I am using this with NSH and the read -r command doesn't work the same. It will only read the first line of the list. I can replace the sleep command, but the script I run has multiple functions and I have no idea how to incorporate everything.

Comment: If `while read` reads only the first line, that means you need to prevent `nexec` from eating the rest. That's an easy fix; if you asked about that problem, we could have told you how to fix it (and if you'd searched for it in the knowledgebase, you'd have found it was already asked and answered).

Comment: ...you can just put the file you're looping over on a file descriptor other than 0, and that'll stop anything else from messing with it. `while IFS= read -r line <&3; do ...; done 3<infile`, and then `infile` is only on stdin for the `read` command and nothing else.

Comment: I can replace the sleep command but with multiple functions in this script not sure how that will work. I also want the progress to be updated every few seconds so its not waiting for everything to complete before updating.

Comment: The point is that you update it **immediately after each thing completes**. That's _better_ than "every few seconds", since it means you're updating it only when it needs to be updated (ie. when something changed), and at no other time.

Comment: ...so, if you replace the `sleep 1` with the process that **actually does the thing whose status you're monitoring/reporting**, then the loop only continues when that thing exits control.

Comment: That's very much similar to how integrating with `dialog` or `pv` would work: Immediately after every time a step you're measuring completes, you write an update to the pipeline they're reading from telling them to update the percentage.

Comment: Yes, dialog doesn't work with nsh. pv isn't available.

Comment: ...of course, you could do the same thing here, writing to a subshell that then updates the user's output at the end of each command. I could see that actually being pretty elegant: `exec 3> >(progress_writer)` at the top of your script; then `echo >&3` every time you finish a chunk of work; and then, inside the `progress_writer` function, you have a `while read` loop that updates the progress bar whenever there's something for it to read.

Comment: What is `nsh`? You're tagging your questions bash; if it's not bash, you need to update the tag appropriately.

Comment: ...if it's http://www.nmedia.net/nsh/, then it's not a POSIX-like shell at all, and has no business with the bash tag whatsoever.

Comment: network shell or powershell. NSH is bmc software that runs in windows. It's part of bladelogic. I believe is based of zsh.

Comment: ...anyhow, **if** the shell you have is zsh-compatible, you can implement a native-shell equivalent to the relevant bits of dialog/pv/whatever very easily -- but "global variables" aren't available for communication between subshells and parent shells; pipelines are (so don't ask the question in a way that assumes an approach that can't possibly work, as this does). And be sure to tag zsh, not bash.